# get child categories with lowest level for product

Tags: mysql, magento

I'm trying to load all categories a product is associated to but only the deepest child category should be selected. For example a product is associated to the categories `women > trousers > jeans` and only `jeans` should be visible.

The code I came up with so far returns the right query but when accessing the collection an sql error is thrown: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cat_path' in 'on clause'`

```
/* @var $_categoryNames Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection */
$_categoryNames = $_product->getCategoryCollection();   

$_categoryNames
    ->joinTable(
        'catalog/category',
        "entity_id = entity_id",
        array('cat_path' => 'path')
    )
    ->getSelect()
    ->where(
        "cat_path not like( CONCAT( path, '/%' ) )"
    );

die($_categoryNames->getSelect());
```

***UPDATE:***
Thanks to blmage I was at least able to find a sql statement to get the right categories:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `catalog_category_entity`e 
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(`entity_id`)
FROM `catalog_category_entity`c
WHERE c.path LIKE (CONCAT(e.path,'%'))
)=1
```

Comment: You can't use a field alias in a `WHERE` clause, and your query won't work because `cat_path` is actually `path` (you join a category on itself). Also, you should use `CONCAT` and not `+` on strings. Anyway, why don't you filter the collection in PHP ?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I wanted to do it in sql because it needs to be loaded for each product and I thought it would be faster this way. You are right, now I'm joing a category on itself. Tried to work with `  ->getSelect()
                ->join()`, too. I'm trying to reproduce the code which generated at least a working query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution for now uses a subselect instead of a join. There might be things left to improve but it works for me.

```
 $_categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();


/** @var $read Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface */
$read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')
    ->getConnection('core_read');

$_categoryIdSelect=$read->select()
    ->from(
        array(
            'c' => $_categories->getTable('catalog/category')
        ),
        'COUNT(e.entity_id)'
    )
    ->where('entity_id IN (?)', $_categoryIds)
    ->where(
        "c.path LIKE (CONCAT(e.path,'%'))"
    );

 /* @var $_categoryNames Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Collection */
$_categoryNames = $_product->getCategoryCollection();       
$_categoryNames->getSelect()
            ->where(
                '2 > (?)',
                new Zend_Db_Expr($_categoryIdSelect)
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$path = "/abc/example";

$_categoryNames->addFieldToFilter('cat_path', array('nlike' => $path));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to compare each `cat_path` to all `paths`. I think this can not be achieved with a filter.